# Why am I getting error-2738 while installing?

Tags: windows

When we tried to install a software we got this error

> Attempt to install commerse server failed on my windows 7 workstation.

We googled and we registered the vbscript based on [this page](http://www.technipages.com/internal-error-2738-install-error-fix.html).

But after successful registering also still the same issue coming.

Can any one suggest a solution to fix it,Is it related to missing system files, wrong system settings or a corrupted registry file or any other issue.

Comment: re-registering VBScript.dll may fix the problem.

Comment: How to do that ,,again the same procees 1. Click Start > Run

2. Type regsvr32 vbscript.dll or some other method..We already registered successfully,then also is it required?

Comment: @peter: 1. Run a command prompt in administrator mode (Start/All Programs/Accessories/ right click on Command Prompt, select Run As Administrator)
2. type:   cd %systemroot%\system32
3. type:   regsvr32 vbscript.dll

Comment: Did you install the software in administrator mode?, right click on the installer and select properties, then compatibility tab, tick the run as admin box, hit OK, try installing it this way.

Comment: Now i am getting this error
"This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid windows installer package."

Comment: @peter: Update Windows with the latest version of Windows Installer. To obtain the latest version of Windows Installer, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=889482fc-5f56-4a38-b838-de776fd4138c&amp;DisplayLang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped:

1. Run a command prompt in Administrator mode (`Start`/`All Programs`/`Accessories`,  right click on Command Prompt, select Run As Administrator)
2. Type: `cd %systemroot%\system32`
3. Type: `regsvr32 vbscript.dll`